# Obtain precision at a certain probability value

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

With scikit-learn, one is able to compute the [precision values](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve) as well the [predicted probability output](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913b/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py#L1637). To compute the precision values, the sklearn precision/recall function takes the true target values as well as the predicted target probability (can be target scores or non-thresholded measure of decisions) as an input, however the computed precision array does not have the same length as the the given predicted probability (precision length = n_thresholds + 1).

Is it somehow possible to compute the precision at a given probability output?

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? Whats wrong with the question?

Comment: Very fundamental question IMO, so I voted to leave open. Could be better worded so that someone with the same problem can find the question.

Comment: "To compute the precision values, the predicted probability is needed" is not true; precision is a metric of hard classifications.  "...those two parameters do not have the same length" - which two parameters? What lengths do they have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everybody else, having a similar problem:
I was able to solve this issue by computing the precision as follows:

```
import numpy as np
# test data
y_true = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1]) 
predicted_prob = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9, 0.5, 0.3])

prob_threshold = 0.7 # your arbitrary cut

n_passed = y_true[predicted_prob > prob_threshold].shape[0]
n_passed_true = y_true[predicted_prob > prob_threshold].sum()

precision = n_passed_true / n_passed
```

Answer (score 0):

With a standard PR curve you will get not only Precision, but also Recall at various prediction probability thresholds.

See [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_precision_recall_curve.html) how to do that with scikit.